# how to set next slide with a jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, slider, fade

Is there a jQuery slider, that I can set next slide (image) number?
I can do this in AnythingSlider, but that can't slide with fade effect?

So: I need a slider which use fade effect, and I can tell it what will be the next image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a colletion of j[Query plugins](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) that will help you so on! Here is the link: 
if you want a slider with fade effect the code below will help ([detailed here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/slideshow.html)):

```
$(".slidetabs").tabs(".images > div", {

    // enable "cross-fading" effect
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeOutSpeed: "slow",

    // start from the beginning after the last tab
    rotate: true

// use the slideshow plugin. It accepts its own configuration
}).slideshow();
```